# Battery Manager not receiving BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC int

Tags: android, widget, power-management

I have a battery widget, and for some reason it does not receive the `BATTERY_PLIGGED_AC` integer when the phone is plugged into AC.

I have another widget for the `BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB` which works just fine.

I can't see anything wrong with my code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    status = intent.getIntExtra("status", BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN);
    batterylevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0); 

    updateAppWidget(context);
}

public void updateAppWidget(Context context){
    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.androidbatterywidget_layout);
    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, "      " + batterylevel + "%");

    if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB)
        updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView2, R.drawable.usb);
    else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC)
        updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView2, R.drawable.bolt);
    else 
        updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView2, R.drawable.empty);
```

Hopefully someone will be able to spot what I have done wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, found a way around it. Wrote a post to answer my own question but as a beginner on stack overflow I have to wait 8 hours until I can reply to my own question. I have saved my answer and will post It in 8 hours, incase people in the future come across the same problem. I have to admit its an odd one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured a way around. Sorry for this post I should have looked at it for a little longer myself. For future reference if people seem to have the same problem, it seems to me that the USB value is bundled with the BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN, but not the AC. So instead all i did was assign a new private int charging, to the value of the BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC variable. If this is true (and the device is charging throygh AC), then the value is 1, so I simply replaced my previous if statement with

```
if (charging == 1)
        updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView2, R.drawable.bolt);
```

Now the code reads;

```
 private int batterylevel = 0;
 private int status;
 private int charging;
   private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
   {

   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {

     status = intent.getIntExtra("status", BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN);
     charging = intent.getIntExtra("plugged", BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC);
     batterylevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0); 

     updateAppWidget(context);

   }


   public void updateAppWidget(Context context){
    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.androidbatterywidget_layout);
    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, "      " + batterylevel + "%");

    if (charging == 1)
        updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView2, R.drawable.bolt); 
    else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB)
            updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView2, R.drawable.usb);
    else 
        updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView2, R.drawable.empty);
```

Im sure that there is a far more "majestic" way to do this, but i was just puzzled at why the USB int was passed if it was plugged into USB (2), but not the AC (1).

Thanks!

Comment: This is incorrect. When BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS ("status") is 2, it just means the battery is charging ("BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING"). It tells nothing about the source. BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB also has a value of 2, hence you apparently got confused.